# Is it possible to set a turn on time for computer using assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, bios

I wonder if it's possible to set a time for the computer to turn itself on.  Maybe an `int ??`/`ah=??` BIOS call?

Are there any interrupts in x86 systems for such work?

P.S. I need to do this on an operation system.

Comment: Why the 8086 tag?  Do you need something that works on actual 8086 hardware?  Or would it be ok to have something that only works on modern desktop PCs?

Comment: Also, do you want to run this code on bare metal, or while an operating system like Windows or Linux is running?  It's highly unlikely this will work from a 16bit DOS program under Windows, because those run in a virtual machine, not talking to the real BIOS on the real hardware.

Comment: Anyway, IDK if real BIOSes support programmatic access to this feature.  I know they do support scheduled wakeup from the BIOS-config screen.  This [interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm) might list such a function if one exists.  That's probably the only useful link for that on [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Comment: AFAIK there's no generic way, you have to talk to the specific BIOS of your motherboard (if it has such capability and if it is exposed to the outside world).

Comment: See also [nvram-wakeup](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/nvram-wakeup.8.html).